# how to write this complex query in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, query-builder

```
SELECT 
    fname,
    lname,
    email,
    phone,
    activities.activitydescription, 
    package.PackageName, 
    reservationyurt.arrvdate 
FROM 
    client
    INNER JOIN activities ON client.activityid = activities.activityid)
    INNER JOIN package ON client.packageid = package.packageid)
    INNER JOIN reservationyurt ON client.packageid = reservationyurt.packageid)
WHERE 
    email = 'tr@gmail.com' 
    AND clientid IN (
        SELECT MAX(clientid)
        FROM client GROUP BY email
    )
```

I want to write this query using the CodeIgniter QueryBuilder. This is what I got so far...

```
$email = array('email' => $this->input->post('email'));
$this->db->select('fname, lname, email, phone, activities.activitydescription, package.pkgname, reservationyurt.arrvdate');
$this->db->from('client');
$this->db->join('activities', 'client.activityid = activities.activityid');
$this->db->join('package', 'client.packageid = package.packageid');
$this->db->join('reservationyurt', 'client.packageid = reservationyurt.packageid');
$this->db->where('email',$email);
$this->db->where('clientid');
```

Comment: can you not just do $this->db->query("YOUR RAW QUERY")

Comment: i want to insert the email variable how can i do that in those quotes ? i did try it using raw query.

Comment: escape: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html. Sometimes just easier for those complex queries with subqueries.

Answer (score 1):

**Hope this will work for you :**

use `where_in` for the last part

```
$this->db->select('fname, lname, email, phone, activities.activitydescription, package.pkgname, reservationyurt.arrvdate');
$this->db->from('client');
$this->db->join('activities', 'activities.activityid = client.activityid');
$this->db->join('package', 'package.packageid = client.packageid');
$this->db->join('reservationyurt', 'reservationyurt.packageid = client.packageid');
$this->db->where('client.email',$email);
$this->db->where_in('client.clientid',"SELECT MAX(clientid) FROM client GROUP BY email)");
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data

Comment: this is working gr8 but i dont know how to read data from this now lol .... how do i return this ? $query = $this->db->get();
   return $query->result_array();  .... this is giving an empty array

Answer (score 0):

Query Builder is a nice tool but you don't always NEED to use it. Unless you have a query that conditionally needs to change the `select`, `where` or someother part of a query it is often much easier to use `query()`

```
$sql = "SELECT 
    fname,
    lname,
    email,
    phone,
    activities.activitydescription, 
    package.PackageName, 
    reservationyurt.arrvdate 
FROM client
    INNER JOIN activities ON client.activityid = activities.activityid)
    INNER JOIN package ON client.packageid = package.packageid)
    INNER JOIN reservationyurt ON client.packageid = reservationyurt.packageid)
WHERE email = ? AND 
    clientid IN (SELECT MAX(clientid) FROM client GROUP BY email)";

$data = array('tr@gmail.com');
$query = $this->db->query($sql, $data);
$dataset = $query->result();
```

Basically what the correct set of Query Builder calls would do is create the string above but it will execute hundreds of lines of code to get there.

Note the use of [Query Binding](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#query-bindings) in `WHERE email = ?`.